Calculating the discontinuity in the scalar potential in a dipole layer
Calculating the discontinuity in the scalar potential in a dipole layer, as can be seen here, we get the following equation (1.89):
$$\Phi_{-}=-\frac{D}{4\pi\varepsilon_{0}}\int_{disk}d\Omega=-\frac{D}{2\varepsilon_{0}}$$
Then:
$$\int_{disk}d\Omega=2\pi$$
But the only interpretation I have is that we're calculating the solid angle for a half-sphere  ($\Omega=2\pi$).
But how does that make sense? As we discussed earlier we would be taking an infinitesimal disk so that $D$ is constant and I don't see any imposition for the surface on which the disk is inserted to be a half sphere. I don't understand why we calculate on a hemisphere.

I don't think we're calculating on a hemisphere, since the integral is over the surface of a disc. So then
$\int_{\mathrm{disc}}\,\,d\Omega = \int_0^{2\pi}\,\,d\Omega = 2\pi.$
The $d\Omega$ represents the area of the disc.

But $d\Omega$ is explicitly said to be a solid angle, not an area

Yes, you're right. But it sweeps out an area after integration.

As stated before, this is the solid angle limited by half a space. (Remember that the solid angle for the whole space is $4\pi$).
If you consider a disk and you get infinitely close to this disk, the solid angle tends towards $\pm 2\pi$. But this is the case for any surface that we approach infinitely closely (from above or below, the side being associated with a change of sign).

I am sorry to ask one more thing, but why I change the sign for $\Phi_+$?
